# how to create query sqlserver in store procedure for display data random

Tags: sql-server-2005

how to create query sqlserver in store procedure for display data random

```
select * from View_lap where codex in ('020573.007','280680.041','020277.006')
```

this code put in store procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE displdata
@ncodex ntext   - 
AS
BEGIN
select * from View_lap where codex in (@ncodex )
```

but i found error

Comment: `but i found error` What error ? Any error message ?

Comment: Did not notice a dash at after the `ntext` ?

Comment: So i assumed you have remove the dash `-` right ?

Comment: if that is the complete code that you post, you missed out the `END`. `BEGIN` must comes with `END`

Comment: how to execute sp from query : exec displdata ('020573.007','280680.041','020277.006') , i have found error Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure displdata, Line 4
Procedure displdata has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: Please start a new question on your last question. This is getting too long for current question